# Apache2 on Debian with ISPConfig giving 403 after updates

Tags: debian, permissions, apache-httpd

I did an update on one of my servers and I am now getting a Forbidden 403 error on the website that is hosted here. The site is getting the error 403. Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) Server

I am running ISPConfig on the server, but I cannot access the web interface and I am having major issues here trying to get this all back up and running.

I have tried to chown the directories to www-data:www-data, root:root, www-data:root, root:www-data and the ISPConfig default for the user/group as well and they are still coming up as no go.

100-example.com.vhost

```
<Directory /var/www/example.com>
  AllowOverride None
  #Order Deny,Allow
  #Allow from all
  Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/web
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
  ErrorLog /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/example.com/error.log
  <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  </IfModule>
  <Directory /var/www/example.com/web>
    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
      SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
    # Clear PHP settings of this website
    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(p[345]?|t|tml)$">
      SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
  </Directory>
  <IfModule mod_suexec.c>
    SuexecUserGroup web1 client1
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    IdleTimeout 300
    ProcessLifeTime 3600
    # MaxProcessCount 1000
    DefaultMinClassProcessCount 0
    DefaultMaxClassProcessCount 100
    IPCConnectTimeout 3
    IPCCommTimeout 600
    BusyTimeout 3600
  </IfModule>
  <Directory /var/www/example.com/web>
    <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
      SetHandler fcgid-script
    </FilesMatch>
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
    Options +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/web>
    <FilesMatch "\.php[345]?$">
      SetHandler fcgid-script
    </FilesMatch>
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php3
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php4
    FCGIWrapper /var/www/php-fcgi-scripts/web1/.php-fcgi-starter .php5
    Options +ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    #Order allow,deny
    #Allow from all
  </Directory>
  <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
    AssignUserId web1 client1
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    <Directory /var/www/clients/client1/web1/webdav>
      <ifModule mod_security2.c>
        SecRuleRemoveById 960015
        SecRuleRemoveById 960032
      </ifModule>
      <FilesMatch "\.ph(p3?|tml)$">
        SetHandler None
      </FilesMatch>
    </Directory>
    DavLockDB /var/www/clients/client1/web1/tmp/DavLock
  </IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

./apache2/error.log:

```
[Wed Mar 25 08:51:02.410279 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 30946] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Wed Mar 25 08:51:05.591034 2020] [:error] [pid 30969] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.7.5+', found '2.7.9'.
[Wed Mar 25 08:51:05.597065 2020] [:error] [pid 30969] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Wed Mar 25 08:51:05.597095 2020] [:error] [pid 30969] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'.
[Wed Mar 25 08:51:05.597166 2020] [:notice] [pid 30969] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Wed Mar 25 08:51:05.597178 2020] [:notice] [pid 30969] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Wed Mar 25 08:51:05.838406 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 31119] [client ::1:36567] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 08:51:06.318757 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30969] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 25 08:51:06.349892 2020] [core:notice] [pid 30969] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Mar 25 08:52:06.072736 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 31119] [client ::1:36578] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 08:53:06.625447 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 31126] [client ::1:36585] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 08:54:09.097197 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 31133] [client ::1:36592] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 08:55:11.511872 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 31137] [client ::1:36599] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 08:55:14.504815 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 31139] [client ::1:36608] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 08:55:27.612502 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 30969] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Mar 25 08:56:35.667755 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 324] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/lib/apache2/suexec)
[Wed Mar 25 08:56:36.725382 2020] [:error] [pid 326] python_init: Python version mismatch, expected '2.7.5+', found '2.7.9'.
[Wed Mar 25 08:56:36.733697 2020] [:error] [pid 326] python_init: Python executable found '/usr/bin/python'.
[Wed Mar 25 08:56:36.733732 2020] [:error] [pid 326] python_init: Python path being used '/usr/lib/python2.7/:/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old:/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload'.
[Wed Mar 25 08:56:36.733809 2020] [:notice] [pid 326] mod_python: Creating 8 session mutexes based on 150 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Wed Mar 25 08:56:36.733821 2020] [:notice] [pid 326] mod_python: using mutex_directory /tmp
[Wed Mar 25 08:56:37.149965 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 326] AH00163: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.7.9 OpenSSL/1.0.1t configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Mar 25 08:56:37.150067 2020] [core:notice] [pid 326] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Mar 25 08:59:04.031419 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 334] [client ::1:36634] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 09:00:05.905401 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 335] [client ::1:36642] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 09:00:07.420178 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 336] [client ::1:36650] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 09:02:04.059978 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 337] [client ::1:36665] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 09:03:03.870050 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 338] [client ::1:36673] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 09:04:05.113235 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 335] [client ::1:36681] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 09:05:05.098343 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 336] [client ::1:36694] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
[Wed Mar 25 09:05:06.604033 2020] [access_compat:error] [pid 334] [client ::1:36702] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/
```

Comment: "I have tried to chown the directories to www-data:www-data" is good, but if you're looking in that direction, there's also "chmod".  What are the permissions of folders and files under /var/www/example.com ?   Also, a couple of lines from the error log wouldn't hurt.

Comment: ./apache/error.log:

Comment: Added error.log file above, and permissions are drwxr-xr-x (755)

Comment: There's a problem with /var/www/html, while this directory doesn't appear in the part of the config you've shared.  What is the URL being used to access the site?  I'm under the impression another part of the config (another vhost?) is intercepting the traffic.

Comment: I have both folders as a clone of each other, so it should not matter which folder it goes to. both are set up the same way. however, the site is cpfa.ca

Comment: It does matter because the problem is not with the folder, but with the apache configuration.  Is there any connection between 100-example.com.vhost and the problematic site?  I'm asking, because the errorlog seems to implicate that we are looking at the wrong config, that 100-example.com.vhost isn't used.

Comment: the vhost file links to the main folder. should i copy the contents of that into the apache2.conf file?

Comment: The apache2.conf should "include" the vhost's file. Isn't that the case?

Comment: So I found an issue and tried to fix it now apache won't start.
ar 26 11:15:25 server1.cpfa.ca apache2[16497]: Output of config test was:
Mar 26 11:15:25 server1.cpfa.ca apache2[16497]: AH00543: apache2: bad user name web1
Mar 26 11:15:25 server1.cpfa.ca apache2[16497]: Action 'configtest' failed.

Comment: Your system doesn't know user web1 (from "AssignUserId web1 client1").  Are you sure this is the consequence of an "upgrade" ??   "client1" is a strange name for a group.  Check with https://www.howtoforge.com/running-vhosts-under-separate-uids-gids-with-apache2-mpm-itk-on-debian-etch

Comment: This is ISPConfig setup. user and group in the system --- web1:x:5004:www-data::/var/www/clients/client1/web1:/bin/false --- ispconfig:x:5004:www-data

Comment: Can you do a "chown -R web1:client1 /var/www/clients/client1/web1" ?

Comment: chown: invalid user: âclient1:web1â  ---  so now I know that there is a lot more here than I can see on the surface.

Comment: Why did you inverse group and user???

Comment: i tried both ways and neither one works. So there is something wrong in my user file

Comment: attempted to delete and recreate the user web1 and it apparenetly does not exist and nothing happens when i run the add...

Comment: how can I over-ride my system to just allow www-data to run everything :P

Comment: I don't know how you could.  I would put the complete Apache configuration aside, and start a new one, piece by piece adding what you need and each time testing if everything still works.

Comment: Fixed it with a very hacked way. I backed up the /etc/apache2/ folder to a separate location, removed the program and reinstalled it. then rebuild the php profile and it is working. it will suffice until I do a full server rebuild. Thank you for all the help

Comment: Good job and you're welcome!